# NotImplentedError on Base classes in Python

Tags: python, testing, inheritance, abstract-class

I was wondering whether this is good practice and how would you test it:

```py
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0

    def process_me(self, value: float):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def process_many(self, values: List[float]):
        for val in values:
            self.process_me(val)


class Sum(Base):
    def process_me(self, value: float):
        self.total += value


class Product(Base):
    def process_me(self, value: float):
        self.total *= value
```

This looks kinda nice, only writing the important method for the children classes `Sum` and `Product`. However, I find two issues developing this code:

1. It's really hard to test! Eventually you have to either test the `process_many` method in each children class or choose one of them, breaking all symmetry in testing. Maybe implement a dummy `process_me` method for the `Base` class and throwing a warning?
2. Maybe this is an example where Abstract Base Classes can be used, however I think I will have a similar problem when trying to testing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inversion of control using base classes is typically quite good for providing a convenient API.

1) As you should typically aim for 100% test coverage, I don't see a huge problem with creating an instance of each of these classes and asserting their expected behavior. Where's the real issue with that? I guess maybe your example is a little oversimplified to tell what's going on. 
If you're worried about big, boilerplate-ish test cases, you could use a declarative model where you define your classes and expected results in a list of dicts (or whichever parametrization mechanism your test library offers) and instantiate them dynamically.

2) Yes, totally use `@abstractmethod` over `NotImplemented` in this case.